# Не форматируется строка в дату

Tags: java, строки, дата

Форматирую строку в дату, но дата выводится все равно в формате типо `Fri Feb 05 00:00:00 MSK 2016` а я хочу именно в формате `yyyy-MM-dd`

```
String s = "2016-02-05";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date m = null;
try {
    m = sdf.parse(s);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

_log.info("Дата: " + m);
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: где "выводится", в `_log.info("Дата: " + m);`? - здесь Вы не указываете никакой формат. NB Вы не "форматируете" строку в дату, а конвертируете или преобразуете.

Comment: а как я должен его указывать?

Comment: Не знаю, например: `_log.info(m.toString(sdf));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы выводите совсем не то, что хотите.

Правильно будет вот так:

```
_log.info("Дата: " + sdf.format(m));
```

То есть Вы должны получить текстовое представление вашего объекта в заданном формате.

Comment: Хм, да а если мне нужно чтоб в переменой типа дата был именно тот формат который я хочу? Т.е. да, выводить через format() получается. Но хотелось бы что б переменая была в таком формате

Comment: "в переменой типа дата" нет формата; она не знает, и не должна знать, как Вы будете ее показывать пользователю.

Comment: Спасибо) тогда буду думать как сделать дальше) 
Но на данный вопрос ответ дан все же верно)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Fri Feb 05 00:00:00 MSK 2016
> ```

Что означает, что дата успешно распарсилась и ты всё делаешь верно.

Ты выводишь **дату**, а не строку. Даты, [как и числа](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988) не являются строками.